# Why is there a mysterious padding around display: inline-block?

Tags: css

The `div` (#second) is spilling beyond its `li` container for `height: 2em;` Only way I can see it happen is due to some mysterious padding within the `li`. But why ? Using `reset.css` (say, by Eric Meyer) doesn't seem to make any difference either. Please help. (For `height: 1em`, there is no problem.)

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/d84e5/

CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 3em;
}
#second {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 2em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li><!--
    --><li><div id="second"></div></li><!--
    --><li>third</li><!--
    --><li>fourth</li><!--
    --><li>fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align:top;` solves the issue (or use `middle` if you want to align the div in the vertical center).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d84e5/2/)

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 3em;
}


#second {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 2em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you use `display: inline-block` your [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) will be in the middle. You can align the element in the middle of the baseline with:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d84e5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The content starts from the middle of the `li`, as the `div` is taller than the `li` it pushes the top of the `li`.

Fix:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 3em;
}
#second {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 1.85em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basing itself off of the line-height.. not padding or margin.  Lower the height to 1.8em or bring down the line-height of the li.